# How to hide other images in swiper?

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

I have a question with swiperjs.
How to hide not active slides with img?
I tried add class with attributes:

```
overflow: hidden
```

but if I added this attributes, images don't appear.
But slider is work.

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-cache-dxw0ei?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Mistakes was in syntax.I add not correct name for class in html.